# SoapFault - faultcode: 'SOAP-ENV:Server' faultstring: 'Procedure 'catalogProductList' not present' faultactor: 'null' detail: null

Tags: java, android, magento, soap, android-ksoap2

This kind of question has been asked in SO . But i didn't get the one i wanted .I am new to magento and android app development . I have configured SOAP api for magento and it is working correctly in my browser , I am using **K2SOAP** library for magento soap sevice .and when i try the same in my android app code .It is just showing me following error

```
SoapFault - faultcode: 'SOAP-ENV:Server' faultstring: 'Procedure 'catalogProductList' not present' faultactor: 'null' detail: null
```

and this is github link of my project

https://github.com/sudhirbelagali/SnowDogSoapAndroid. Please consider this..

So please help me

Comment: did you solve this problem?

Comment: s sir I have done this

Comment: will you please provide the solution?

Comment: s sir i can provide u ,

Answer (score 1):

I got this answer , I have used this **catalogProductList** method to fetch catalog product list , and it is not available in SOAP of V1 version and again i called the same method with SOAP V2 version , it worked , So you have to disable WS1 compliance at the Magento admin panel in order to work with SOAP V2 version , If u need more than this answer Please comment here